# Discord.js - Setting the Avatar

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am using discord.js for building a bot in nodejs. It is hosted in Replit. Below, is the code I am using to send a message, containing the sender's avatar. But, unfortunately, it doesn't work as expected ! (couldn't see the image ).

[image]

```
client.on("message", msg => {
 if (msg.channel.name === 'bot-is-here') {
    if (msg.content === "avatar") {

      const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Avatar!')
        .setAuthor("Your Avatar", msg.author.avatar)
        .setImage(msg.author.avatar)
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        .setDescription('Avatar URL')

      msg.reply(embed);
    }
  }
})
```

Any help is greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Avatar](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=avatar) is a property of an User object which returns the ID of the user's avatar as a String. In order do get the avatar of the user, you need to do `msg.author.avatarURL()` or `msg.author.displayAvatarURL()`. The difference between these two is that, the [avatarURL()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=avatarURL) method returns the avatar if the user, only if it's present. The [displayAvatarURL()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=displayAvatarURL) method returns the user's avatar if they have one. Otherwise a link to their default avatar will be returned.